# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'from') when trying import jsonwebtoken on vuejs 3

Tags: vue.js, jwt, vite

i'm just trying to import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken' into ts file, but i show some waring and error

```
[WARN] Module "buffer" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "buffer.Buffer" in client code. See http://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'from')
    at node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js (index.js:12:12)
    at __require (chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=8a6e712d:3:50)
    at node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js (sign-stream.js:2:14)
    at __require (chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=8a6e712d:3:50)
    at node_modules/jws/index.js (index.js:2:18)
    at __require (chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=8a6e712d:3:50)
    at node_modules/jsonwebtoken/decode.js (decode.js:1:11)
    at __require (chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=8a6e712d:3:50)
    at node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js (index.js:2:11)
    at __require (chunk-76J2PTFD.js?v=8a6e712d:3:50)
```

i'm trying to import by another way like

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
```

but seem vite doesn't support require. Are there anybody get this error, how to fix that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not a frontend library.  These are node functions being used that can't be run in a browser.  It is meant for server-side only.

Comment: oh i understand , but are there anyway to run it on browser ?